# Why is only the first element of the output wrong?

Tags: arrays, c, reverse

I have recently started practicing on C. The output is reversed except for first element. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?
I also tried using for loop but that is displaying the array as it is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int temp;
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter value of n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array1[n];
    int k=0,j=n;
    printf("Enter the five numbers\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the number %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&array1[i]);
    }
    printf("The array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",array1[i]);

    }
    while(k<j)
    {
        temp=array1[k];
        array1[k]=array1[j];
        array1[j]=temp;
        j--;
        k++;
    }
    printf("\nThe array after reversing is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",array1[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: `int k=0,j=n;` You set your last index to `n` - but C arrays are zero-based and the last index is really `n - 1`.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `array1[k]` to `array1[j]` and you initialized `j` to `n`, so it swaps the value in `array1[k]` with `array1[j]` => in the first iteration, the value `j` = `n`, however the index of the final element is `n-1`. (indexes are 0,1,2,3,4,...n-1). So it tries to get the value of position n, where there is actually no value stored ( it is outside the array ). Change `j` to `n-1` in `int k=0,j=n;`